Can you successfully substitute pickled onions for baby onions in Coq Au Vin?
We can rarely get white baby onions where we are, but jarred, pickled miniature onions are easily obtained. These will be drained, soaked in a large bowl of water overnight, and rinsed before being cooked with the chicken and wine etc. I was considering using a solution containing baking soda (Sodium Bicarbonate) to soak the onions in, but I suspect this will cause more problems than it solves.
Will this be sufficient to remove any tartness and trace of acidity? I will probably add a touch of sugar to balance out any bitterness in the wine for good measure. Balsamic vinegar is often added to stews etc, so I am generally happy with the flavour profile, I'm just more concerned that when biting on an onion it will reveal that it was previously pickled.
Will this approach be sufficient to disguise such an outrageous substitution?

It's all about the tannic note and you want to add sugar?

Quite a few CoV recipes advocate adding a small amount sugar to balance out any bitterness, this is particularly important if tomato purée is used and it on the tart side. Traditionally, the onions were cooked separately in a water/sugar solution, so this may be the origins of it.

Cooking isn't magic that opens a portal to Hell if you don't exactly follow the recipe.  Maybe you'll like the added tartness.

Years of experience has taught me just that, @RonJohn. The only recipies that really need to be followed exactly are generally baked goods etc. where measurements are critical.  Soups, stews etc. are generally much more forgiving.

Unfortunately, that won't work. Pickled onions will still taste pickled, and add a sour note to the dish. Soaking them in a solution of sodium bicarbonate will just make them taste sour and a bit acrid at the same time.
Substitute shallots or white onion instead.
